# How can I run an application compiled by CodeDom as an administrator?

Tags: c#

I want to add app.manifest file to codedom compiler for run compiled file as adminstrator.

Thanks

Comment: When you need to reverse-engineer the CompilerParameters you need then a simple way to do so is by doing this is a normal project first.  Use Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run, "MSBuild project build output verbosity".  Crank it up to eleven and look at the Output window for the compile command.

Comment: @HansPassant Hello, Thanks for your comment. But I want to make for basic IDE. And I need to do something for write file. I need to adminstrator permissions. I wanted to mean, "How to add app.manifest file to compiled by my IDE"

Comment: If you work on an IDE product, then take a look at Roslyn instead of CodeDOM. That's a true compiler you can use or customize.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you so much!